# integral of function powered n.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

z' = z'(x); z is  function of x

c= constant.

Function is 
F = z'{^n} e^y $

and this the operation needed to be done.

$ z' (\frac{dF}{dz'}) - F = c $

so I started with.

$ = [z' n ( z'^{n-1} e^y)] -[z'{^n} e^y] = c $

z' from outsdide in first term multiplies to z' inside the small brackets

$ [ n(z'^{n-1+1} e^y) ] - [z'^n e^y] = c$

$ [ n(z'^{n} e^y] - [z'^n e^y] = c$

(Q1- is that right so far ?)
doing minus operation gives

$ (n-1)(z'^n e^y)  = c  $

now to get z out of z'

$ \int dx (n-1)(z')^n =  \int dx \frac{c}{e^y}$

(Q2: what happens next ?)

how do I get?
$ z=n \, ln((constant)\, x+e^{1/n}  ? $

BC is $ y(0) =1 , y(1)= A  $

where $ constant = e^{A/n} - e^{1/n} $

Comment: What do you need to find?

Comment: I need to find equation of z (not z primed.)
Then I have to apply some boundary conditions on it. 
Please let me know if at (Q1) all I did was right way of doing things ?

Comment: What equation? Can you write down the expression or function you need to find and put a question mark in front of it? I can't make much sense of the post

Comment: I am trying to find stationary path. Which should come from z after (z'(dF/dz') - F = c) is applied on F.
That path should look like 
|
$ z= n\, ln ((constant)\,x + e^{1/n}) $
=============

constant in above equation $= e^{A/n} - e^{1/n}$

Comment: [Check this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

First, explaining the meaning/origin of your equation can be a good idea.

Next: all OK until
$$(n-1)(z'^n e^y)  = c.$$
But now... $y$ is $y$ (another variable $\ne x$) or is actually $x$? In any case,
$$z'  = \root n\of{\frac{ce^{-y}}{(n-1)}} = \root n\of{\frac{c}{(n-1)}}e^{-y/n}.$$
And if $y$ is actually $x$, integrating:
$$z = -n\root n\of{\frac{c}{(n-1)}}e^{-x/n}+k.$$